# Why won't Visual Studio 2008 create .mdf files with SQL Server 2008 Developer installed?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008

I'm trying some of the ASP.NET MVC tutorials and one of them has the following steps:

- Right-click on the "App_Data" folder, and choose "Add New item"
- Choose "SQL Server Database" under the "Data" category.

However, once I do that, I get the following message from Visual Studio:

> Connections to SQL Server files (*.mdf) require SQL Server Express 2005 to function proprely. Please verify the installation of the component or download from the URL...

The thing is that I have SQL Server 2008 Developer Edition installed, and I would really rather not install any Express versions (2005 or 2008) if I don't have to. Is there a work-around for this issue?

Comment: Ken's answer should actually be the accepted answer. It's a bug in Visual Studio 2008 that requires a hotfix. It has to do with installing a 64-bit version of SQL Server Express and Visual Studio 2008 SP1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/293281/why-wont-visual-studio-2008-create-mdf-files-with-sql-server-2008-developer-ins/1582599#1582599

Comment: I don't believe so; he is still talking about using SQL Server Express where I was describing a situation with SQL Server Developer edition. GalacticCowboy's explanation is still valid, as far as I know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually SQL express is a whole different database engine then SQL Server 2005. So yes if you want to use mdf files you'd need SQL Express.

Comment: Oh, so that means I'll have to use the normal approach of creating a separate database and referencing it in the project rather than what the tutorials suggest. Thanks :)

Comment: That's very misleading statement. SQL Express and the full SQL Server product actually do share the very same database engine  (and virtually everything else). The reason why the full server doesn't support user instance databases is beyond me, but it was most likely either a business decision or one routed in security. Implementation-wise, all the bits are there.

Comment: Actually they are not the same (hence the differences).  The sort and optimizers are different, multi cpu usage, memory allocation routines, lots of changes.  They may be FUNCTIONALLY the same, but are quite different under the hood.  

The reason the probably don't support them is they perform terribly.  It is not a best practice to use them in anything short of demos.  File based connections are quite a bit slower.

Answer (score 12):

I ran into this problem too on 64-bit Windows 7 (using 64-bit SQL Server Express 2008).

There are two methods of fixing this problem referenced in the [Microsoft Support Knowledge Base article](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;957944):

**1. Workaround**

> To work around this problem, uninstall
>   the 64-bit version of SQL Server
>   Express 2008, and then install the
>   32-bit version of SQL Server Express
>   2008.

If you don't want to do the uninstall/install, then try the Hotfix method below.

**2. Hotfix**

> A supported hotfix is now available
>   from Microsoft. However, it is
>   intended to correct only the problem
>   that this article describes. Apply it
>   only to systems that are experiencing
>   this specific problem.

Although the article itself doesn't include a link to the hotfix, you can get it here:
http://support.microsoft.com/hotfix/KBHotfix.aspx?kbnum=957944

Answer (score 7):

To illuminate masfenix's reply, SQL Express supports one feature that is not supported by full-blown SQL Server: a "user instance" database.  With SQL Express installed and an mdf file in your App_Data folder, the application will dynamically attach and detach it as needed.  For hobbyist or small business sites, this may be perfect.  If you're running SQL elsewhere in the enterprise, you probably don't want to go this route and therefore the feature isn't useful to you.

Answer (score 2):

I want to point out that I have both Developer edition and Express edition installed. And I still run into the same error. I think Express edition must be installed as a single instance.

Comment: You should make sure that Visual Studio knows about your instance of SQL Server. Go to Visual Studion -> Tools -> Database Tools -> Data Connections -> [Instance Name]. Make sure it lists the correct instance name for your SQL Express (usually "SQLEXPRESS").

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem but I've sql 2008 express installed.
any way to make it work with sql 2008 express so I don't have to install the 4th sql instance on my machine??
I already have sql 2005, sql 2008, sql 2008 express

what the F... :)

Comment: You should make sure that Visual Studio knows about your instance of SQL Server. Go to Visual Studion -> Tools -> Database Tools -> Data Connections -> [Instance Name]. Make sure it lists the correct instance name for your SQL Express (usually "SQLEXPRESS").

Comment: Why not just create a database in one of the other 3 instances you have installed and use it?  Why bother with a file based connection at all?